# How to get rails3 to do remote link using database info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink, link-to

the url comes from a database table, e.g. www.test.com.

How do I get a working link if that url is stored in the database (as 'web site' column).

I tried:

```
<%= link_to(company.web_site, company.web_site, :remote => true) %>
```

but I got http://localhost:3000/company_name.com
and I can't seem to get rid of the localhost for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<%= link_to(company.web_site, "http://#{company.web_site}", :remote => true) %>` Hint it with "http://" string would do the trick.

Or prepend the url with `http://` or `https://` in your database at the fist place also be an alternative way.

Comment: Thanks but that did not work.

Rolling over the link still shows `http://localhost:3000/www.thesite.com/`

The source shows `<a href="www.thesite.com" data-remote="true">www.thesite.com</a>`

Comment: My brain getting worse. Hint it with "http://" would solve your problem. I also have updated my post.